# .gitignore all except one specific file (via a full/fuller file path)

Tags: powershell, gitignore

### The Goal:

How to use `.gitignore` to exclude all folders & files **except** PowerShell $Profile?

The answer should help expand the current *exception file list* to more files in other subfolders. If possible, reduce wildcards to minimum, and use **as specific as possible (full/fuller file path)**. Why? For instance, `Book1.xlsx` may exist in multiple subfolders but I want to be able to choose only the specific desired subfolders.

Thanks in advance!

---

### Current status:

On Windows 10 (not Linux Distros):

1. `git init` initiated on top level directory `C:\`. [Please don't suggest to start from other subfolders. Just remain with `C:\`, as I will include more files to the exception list]
2. `C:\.gitignore` containing the below:

```
    # Ignore All
    /*
    
    # Exception List [eg. PowerShell's $Profile (please use FULL/FULLER FILE PATH, if possible)]
    !.gitignore
    
    !Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
    
    !Users/John/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
    !Users\John\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

    !C:/Users/John/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
    !C:\Users\John\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

3. With the above codes, `git status` successfully returned only `.gitignore` as 1 untracked file. `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` remained missing from untrack listing.
4. I've tried alternative ways (wildcard, partial subfolder name with pattern, etc) but **all failed** to return the  **fuller file path *PowerShell $Profile***.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with .gitignore but I have at least looked at the documentation before so I know a little :)  Could be that this applies?  [An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. ] https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Comment: The `not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.` part